# Pass a single number through an iFrame with permission restrictions

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

I am working on a sort of operating-system like program and in it, iframes are used to display different programs. I am working on a function that will allow devs to automatically close their frames, like a sys.exit(). The only thing I need is a single number uniquely identifying the iframe which contains the dev's program - be it an id, name, whatever. Problem is the security error, since everything is local. I have complete control over the frame. Also jquery is to be avoided, but available if necessary.

[EDIT]

the security error is: "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match"

Any ideas?

Much appreciated,

-Dylan

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the "security error" ?

Comment: Each iframe should have a unique id. But without any structure it is difficult  to tell you how to access it.

Comment: @Roberto, I have included the error in an edit

Comment: It is most likely caused by [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). There are solutions, but it would be helpful to first see the code that creates these frames.

Comment: It is almost certainly SOP. Perhaps I can create a ghost element inside the frame with an id/ name to give pass through my data?

Comment: Why has nobody mentioned postMessage? Is there a disadvantage to it that makes it obsolete? It took me a while to find.

Answer (score 0):

Give your iframe an ID:

```
<iframe id="iframeId"></iframe>
```

On the hosting page

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow;

iframe.postMessage('close', 'http://yourdomain');
```

Then in your iframe you need to do this:

```
addEventListener("close", functionToCloseWindow, false);
var functionToCloseWindow = function(){
window.close();
}
```

Here's some info on the postMessage() API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this solution does. Can you please explain it more?

Comment: Sure. Basically you need to use postMessage() to communicate between your hosting site and the iframe. It's a security measure. It lets you pass strings. You can pass the string 'close' and listen to it on the other side, invoking the function to close the window once it's received. Hope that clarifies :-)

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately this is all local, and my issue is same-origin policy

Comment: @AlgoRythm yeah - and check out the solution in the page Roberto linked to - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access